# Explaining the yesterday vote in US House on Mayorkas imeachment

Tags: united-states, law, house-rules

I read in today news the following sentence:

> Rep. Blake Moore (R-Utah), the chair of the GOP conference, flipped
> his vote to “no” seconds before the vote closed, a procedural maneuver
> that allows the conference to bring the legislation back to the floor
> at a later date.

Can anybody explain why this was needed and what would happen by the final vote 215-215?

Comment: I think this is covered by the linked duplicate - in order to bring a motion to reconsider, the representative that brings the motion must have been in opposition to the vote in the first instance.

Comment: @CDJB: 'splainer of Fox News agrees that was the case/motivation here [too]:  https://www.foxnews.com/politics/hitchhikers-guide-why-rep-blake-moore-flipped-from-yea-nay-impeaching-mayorkas As for the other Q,  215-215 means the motion/law etc. is rejected, according to House rules.